# Рисование кривой Безье в d3.js

Tags: вёрстка, svg, d3.js

Как нарисовать линию с помощью метода bezierCurveTo в d3.js, чтобы линии выглядели как на изображении ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я даю ссылку на [кривую Безье](https://javascript.info/bezier-curve), но мне ничего не известно об этом.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Drawing bezierCurve in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60293272/7394871) от участника  [@ferozcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490341/ferozcoder).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60293272/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Есть много способов сделать это. Для этого можно создать [собственную кривую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1266363/28748).

Но мы могли бы сделать это и попроще. Данные, передаваемые генератору ссылок, например `d3.linkHorizontal`, из макета d3 обычно содержат свойства источника и цели, каждое из которых обычно содержит свойства x и y. Предполагая эту структуру, мы могли бы создать функцию, которая использует их, создает и возвращает соответствующие данные пути с кривой Безье:

```
var linker = function(d) {
  var x0 = d.source.x;
  var y0 = d.source.y;
  var y1 = d.target.y;
  var x1 = d.target.x;
  var k = 120;
  
  var path = d3.path()
  path.moveTo(y0,x0)
  path.bezierCurveTo(y1-k,x0,y0,x1,y1-k,x1);
  path.lineTo(y1,x1);
  
  return path.toString();
}
```

Вышеупомянутый код довольно простой, в нем используется `d3.path`, но вы можете легко создать  SVG path самостоятельно. В Интернете есть множество интерактивных исследователей кривой Безье, чтобы вы могли выяснить, какие контрольные точки работают лучше всего. Поскольку дерево, которое я использовал, вертикальное, я повернул его горизонтально, инвертируя `x` и `y`, поэтому мои координаты `[y, x]`. Я использую `k` выше, чтобы сместить кривую Безье на небольшую часть общей ссылки слева:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вы можете легко поиграть с этим, чтобы поместить кривую в середину ссылки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот это в действии:

```js
var data = { "name": "Parent", "children": [ 
    { "name": "Child A", "children": [ { "name": "Grandchild1"}, {"name":"Grandchild2" } ] }, 
    { "name": "Child B", } 
    ] };

var width = 400;
var height = 300;

margin = {left: 50, top: 10, right:30, bottom: 10}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);
      
var g = svg.append("g").attr('transform','translate('+ margin.left +','+ margin.right +')');

var root = d3.hierarchy(data);
      
var tree = d3.tree()
   .size([height-margin.top-margin.bottom,width-margin.left-margin.right]);
   
var linker = function(d) {
  var x0 = d.source.x;
  var y0 = d.source.y;
  var y1 = d.target.y;
  var x1 = d.target.x;
  var k = (y1-y0)/2;
  
  var path = d3.path()
  path.moveTo(y0,x0)
  path.lineTo(y0+k/2,x0)
  path.bezierCurveTo(y1-k,x0,y0+k,x1,y1-k/2,x1);
  path.lineTo(y1,x1);
  
  return path.toString();
}

 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(tree(root).links())
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", linker);

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);
      
  node.append("text")
     .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
     .attr('y',-10)
     .attr('x',-10)
     .attr('text-anchor','middle');
```

```css
.node circle {
          fill: #fff;
          stroke: steelblue;
          stroke-width: 3px;
        }

        .link {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #ccc;
          stroke-width: 2px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Но, читая комментарии, я заметил, что ваш вопрос может быть больше о `dagreD3`, что значительно меняет ситуацию. `Dagre D3` предлагает большую простоту использования по сравнению с `D3` за счет некоторой гибкости D3. Если вы хотите предоставить DagreD3 кривую определенного типа, вам следует использовать кривую d3 или некоторую настраиваемую кривую (как в связанном ответе выше). Вы можете достаточно легко указать кривую при добавлении ребер.

Но это не решает проблему краев, исходящих из той же точки, что и на вашем изображении. Я предоставлю решение на основе d3, которое, вероятно, нарушает размещение меток краев, `transitions` и т.д., Поэтому его следует немного доработать, если вам нужна эта функциональность. Я воспользуюсь генератором Безье сверху. На это вдохновлено следующее:

```js
var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph()
  .setGraph({rankdir: 'LR'})
  .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function() { return {}; });

g.setNode(0,  { label: "0"});
g.setNode(1,  { label: "1"});
g.setNode(2,  { label: "2"});
g.setNode(3,  { label: "3"});
g.setNode(4,  { label: "4"});

g.setEdge(0, 1);
g.setEdge(0, 2);
g.setEdge(1, 3);
g.setEdge(1, 4);

var render = new dagreD3.render().createEdgePaths(createEdgePaths);


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    svgGroup = svg.append("g"),
    zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
      svgGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    });
svg.call(zoom);

render(svgGroup, g);

function createEdgePaths(selection, g, arrows) {
   selection.selectAll("g.edgePath")
    .data(g.edges())
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", function(e) {
      return calcPoints(g,e);  
    });
}

function calcPoints(g, e) {
  var source = g.node(e.v);
  var target = g.node(e.w);
  var x0 = source.x + source.width/2;
  var x1 = target.x - target.width/2;
  var y0 = source.y;
  var y1 = target.y;
  return linker(x0,y0,x1,y1)
}
function linker(x0,y0,x1,y1) {
 var dx = x1 -x0;
 var k = dx/3;
      
 var path = d3.path()
 path.moveTo(x0,y0)
 path.bezierCurveTo(x1-k,y0,x0,y1,x1-k,y1);
 path.lineTo(x1,y1);
      
 return path.toString();
}
```

```css
path {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  fill: none;
}
rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke:black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dagre-d3@0.6.1/dist/dagre-d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" height="600"></svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60305605/7394871) от участника  [@Andrew Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106086/andrew-reid).</sub>