# Плоская кривая графика реакции d3 + vx в каждой точке данных

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

Я пытаюсь построить что-то вроде таких линий  https://dribbble.com/shots/2673159-Funnel-UI-concept/attachments/538068

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я просмотрел все кривые, предоставленные `d3/vx`, и, похоже, ни одна из них не имеет кривой между каждым отдельным шагом с прямой линией в точке данных. Есть ли тип кривой, который мне не хватает, который был бы похож на приведенный на картинке выше?
Если нет, и для этого нужна настраиваемая кривая, есть ли где-нибудь более подробное описание того, как реализовать настраиваемые кривые, чем в документации d3?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [d3 + vx react chart curve flat at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55231234/7394871) от участника  [@mikeg542](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495587/mikeg542).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55231234/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Стандартной кривой для этого не существует; однако это может быть возможно, если продублировать добавление дополнительных точек, чтобы заставить стандартную кривую d3 быть плоской там, где это необходимо. Например, добавление точек до и после этапа меняется на одно и то же значение `y`.

Однако настраиваемая кривая может работать и избавить от необходимости манипулировать данными. Кривая Безье должна помочь c отправной точкой, пунктом назначения и контрольными точками, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение с [Codepen](https://codepen.io/explosion/pen/YGApwd)

Чтобы реализовать эту идею, мы можем заменить точечную функцию в стандартной кривой, такой как `d3.curveLinear`, на ту, которая рисует кривую Безье.

Точечная функция `d3.curveLinear` для сравнения:

```
function(x, y) {
    x = +x, y = +y;
    switch (this._point) {
      case 0: this._point = 1; this._line ? this._context.lineTo(x, y) : this._context.moveTo(x, y); break;
      case 1: this._point = 2; // proceed
      default: this._context.lineTo(x, y); break;
    }
```

И новая функция точки:

```
function(x,y) {
    x = +x, y = +y;
    switch (this._point) {
      case 0: this._point = 1; 
        this._line ? this._context.lineTo(x, y) : this._context.moveTo(x, y);
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
      case 1: this._point = 2;
      default:  
        var x1 = this.x0 * 0.5 + x * 0.5;
        this._context.bezierCurveTo(x1,this.y0,x1,y,x,y); // bezierCurveTo(controlPoint1X,controlPoint1Y,controlPoint2X,controlPoint2Y,endPointX,endPointY)
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
    }
  }
  return custom;
}
```

*Я использую одно и то же значение x для каждой контрольной точки, это может быть не идеально, поскольку они могут быть недостаточно плоскими на концах, но это легко изменить*

Мы можем создать собственную кривую, используя d3.curveLinear и подставив в эту новую точечную функцию:

```
var curve = function(context) {
  var custom = d3.curveLinear(context);
  custom._context = context;
  custom.point = function(x,y) {
    x = +x, y = +y;
    switch (this._point) {
      case 0: this._point = 1; 
        this._line ? this._context.lineTo(x, y) : this._context.moveTo(x, y);
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
      case 1: this._point = 2;
      default: 
        var x1 = this.x0 * 0.5 + x * 0.5;
        this._context.bezierCurveTo(x1,this.y0,x1,y,x,y); 
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
    }
  }
  return custom;
}
```

Это работает достаточно легко:

```js
var curve = function(context) {
  var custom = d3.curveLinear(context);
  custom._context = context;
  custom.point = function(x,y) {
    x = +x, y = +y;
    switch (this._point) {
      case 0: this._point = 1; 
        this._line ? this._context.lineTo(x, y) : this._context.moveTo(x, y);
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
      case 1: this._point = 2;
      default: 
        var x1 = this.x0 * 0.5 + x * 0.5;
        this._context.bezierCurveTo(x1,this.y0,x1,y,x,y);
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
    }
  }
  return custom;
}

var data = [
 [10,10],
 [160,50],
 [310,100]
];

var line = d3.line()
  .curve(curve);
  
d3.select("svg")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",line(data));
  
d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate("+d+")";
  })
  .attr("r",3)
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width:1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

А вот демонстрация области, которая рисует воронку для каждого этапа. В зависимости от ваших данных это может быть или не быть предпочтительным. Мои подобранные данные структурированы по этапам, поэтому проще всего нарисовать каждый этап индивидуально. Объединить все этапы в один `path/area` может будет немного сложнее.

```js
var curve = function(context) {
  var custom = d3.curveLinear(context);
  custom._context = context;
  custom.point = function(x,y) {
    x = +x, y = +y;
    switch (this._point) {
      case 0: this._point = 1; 
        this._line ? this._context.lineTo(x, y) : this._context.moveTo(x, y);
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
      case 1: this._point = 2;
      default: 
        var x1 = this.x0 * 0.5 + x * 0.5;
        this._context.bezierCurveTo(x1,this.y0,x1,y,x,y);
        this.x0 = x; this.y0 = y;        
        break;
    }
  }
  return custom;
}

var data = [
  {stage:1, start:1,end:0.5},
  {stage:2, start:0.5,end:0.2},
  {stage:3, start:0.2,end:0.1},
  {stage:4, start:0.1,end:0.005}
]

var yRangeMax = 100;
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([yRangeMax,0]);
  
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([50,400])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.stage;
  }))

var svg = d3.select("svg");
 
var area = d3.area()
  .curve(curve)
  .y1(function(d) { return yRangeMax*2-d[1]; })
  .y0(function(d) { return d[1]; })

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var p1 = [x(d.stage),y(d.start)]
    var p2 = [x(d.stage)+x.step(),y(d.end)]
    return area([p1,p2])
  })
```

```css
path{
  stroke: #bbb;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
```

Что касается руководства по пользовательским кривым, я не видел много ресурсов. Однако эти ответы ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40729164/7106086), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574541/7106086)) могут оказаться полезными.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55251182/7394871) от участника  [@Andrew Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106086/andrew-reid).</sub>